# c# WinForm: Remove or Customize the 'Focus Rectangle' for Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to disable or better yet draw your own focus rectangle for a regular button control! (that dotted line seems so Windowss 95ish)

I've noticed that the control properties (FOR BUTTONS) does not have a ownerdrawfixed setting (which I don't know if that's even the route to use for the solution, although i've seen it used for customizing other controls).

Answer (score 15):

Getting this right is trickier than it sounds.  No doubt one of the reasons that custom button painting isn't overridable.  This worked as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;

class MyButton : Button {
    private VisualStyleRenderer renderer;
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (this.Focused && Application.RenderWithVisualStyles && this.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Standard) {
            if (renderer == null) {
                VisualStyleElement elem = VisualStyleElement.Button.PushButton.Normal;
                renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(elem.ClassName, elem.Part, (int)PushButtonState.Normal);
            }
            Rectangle rc = renderer.GetBackgroundContentRectangle(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
            rc.Height--;
            rc.Width--;
            using (Pen p = new Pen(Brushes.DarkGray)) {
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This code works great, but I don't understand how - there are no attributes (like [Browseable]) that are normally specified for custom controls? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, there are no added properties.  It just replaces the painting.

Comment: Really amazing, by simply overriding a method in a base control, you can create a new control!

Answer (score 15):

A quick and easy way to disable the focus rectangle all together is to subclass the control and include this code:

```
public class CustomButton : Button  
{  
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues  
    {  
        get 
        {  
            return false;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me - I can still get a rectangle on the button through tab or arrow keys.

Comment: Like @theJerm, this isn't working for me either, under net 4.5

Comment: @Memetican, I'm wondering if it works for you under a lower .NET version? It seems odd that it would stop working in later versions though.

Answer (score 2):

Just simple way.

Set

```
button.FlatStyle = Flat;
button.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
button.TabStop = false;
```

> FlatAppearance.BorderColor

set on code cause could not transparent color set in design mode.

Comment: Why not just set `BorderSize` to 0? If you want a horridly ugly flat button, that is.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have to use both solutions above to make it work.

```
public class ButtonNoFocus : Button
{
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public override void NotifyDefault(bool value)
    {
        base.NotifyDefault(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the Button class and override OnPaint. If your override does not call base.OnPaint, nothing will be drawn for the button and you will have complete control (including the focus rectangle).

Answer (score 0):

One quick/dirty solution that I found (for removing the focus rectangle only) was explicitly defining the background color. For the default control color, for ex:

```
this._dropDownButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F0F0F0");
```

EDIT: Apparently this doesn't work. It was being fixed in my case for an unrelated reason. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using `BackgroundImage` to set an image on the button. When the user pressed 'Tab', my image button got a black rectangle.

The solution that worked for me is:

1. Call for [NotifyDefault(false)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.notifydefault?view=net-5.0) for every button I used.
2. Set the `TabStop` property to false for every button I used.

Tested on .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to hide the focus frame would be to switch the focus from buttons to a dummy control as soon as the button has been clicked:

```
public frmMain()
{
    ...
    RemoveControlFocusFrame(this);
}

private void RemoveControlFocusFrame(Control c)
{
    if (c.Controls.Count == 0)
    {
        if (c is Button || c is CheckBox)
            c.GotFocus += (o, e) => lblFocusDump.Focus();
        return;
    }

    foreach (Control sub in c.Controls)
        RemoveControlFocusFrame(sub);
}
```

The dummy lblFocusDump label has its Visible set to true and can be hidden in Designer by pushing it to background behind any other control.