# How to disable dots in around the controls in c#.net

Tags: c#

Hi there i want to disable the dots around the controls when user selected it (for example in a tab control ) but I can't. I tried to set false all fields in controls properties but nothing happened.

[image]

Comment: Programmers call those "the focus rectangle"

Comment: Try using `outline: none`

Comment: as @Plutonix said that is one of the term your are looking for. You should easily find alot of solutions that is using an override of the `OnPaint` method of the control.

Comment: @ikaikastine this is winforms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700534/c-sharp-winform-remove-or-customize-the-focus-rectangle-for-buttons