# Annoying Border around button when pressing tab and clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I get this very annoying border when pressing tab and the clicking the button

I've tried

```
 foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
 {
   if (x is Button)
            {
                Button newbut = (Button)x;
                newbut.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                newbut.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 255, 255);
                newbut.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                newbut.TabStop = false;
            }
        }
```

And I've also tried doing adding an event on Keydown and not allowing to press the tab key but nothing has worked so far.

[image]

this is example of the border that keeps popping up

Comment: Please don't try to remove borders from controls, they are there for a reason. In this case, tabbing is often used by people who can't use a mouse so if you change that style, you are effectively making your app completely inaccessible.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700534/c-sharp-winform-remove-or-customize-the-focus-rectangle-for-buttons

Comment: I already tried that code @RobertBaron, and I know that but it's for personal use DavidG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# WinForm: Remove or Customize the 'Focus Rectangle' for Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700534/c-sharp-winform-remove-or-customize-the-focus-rectangle-for-buttons)

Comment: @Stefan I tried the top solution, the second one regarding a custom button class wouldn't work in my case since I have the buttons already made

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by generating own button class and editing the designer.cs file

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want custom buttons, you can shift focus to another control once finished, this prevents the rectangle from showing. You could place a dummy control out of view and shift fucus to this.

```
    private void btnDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDummyControl.Focus();

        MessageBox.Show("This still executes even though we have lost focus");

        // If you are decoupling your code from the UI, this becomes second nature quickly as it becomes part of your control handling.
    }
```

Also you can stop the control from getting Tab focus my setting it's TabStop property tp false, do this in the buttons Paint event.

If you have many buttons, you can just point them to the same event handler (On_Paint).

```
    private void On_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Button thisButton = sender as Button;
        thisButton.TabStop = false;
    }
```